# Aggregating analyses over sbt subprojects

Tags: scala, sbt

In sbt, if I use `mapR` on the `compile` task, I can get an `Analysis` object that will let me harvest warnings and other information. This allows me to keep track of project-specific warning statistics programmatically.

However, I have many subprojects aggregated under a root project, using sbt's aggregation functionality. Is there an idiomatic way to aggregate this information (or arbitrary information) up an aggregation tree like this? For example, if I wanted to know the total number of warnings in the entire build, how might I do that? I can maintain global Scala-level state within my sbt project and add to an `AtomicInteger` after each project's `compile` step, but that feels ugly and I feel like there must be a better way.

For context, I want to tell TeamCity the total number of warnings in the build, so I need to be able to aggregate information like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a straightforward way that is specific to getting the Analysis, but only if all of the `Analysis` values that you want are on a classpath.
In sbt, a classpath has type `Seq[Attributed[File]]`.
The [Attributed](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/api/#sbt.Attributed) part attaches metadata to each entry.
One piece of metadata is the `Analysis` for that entry (obviously only if it was compiled from source).

So, this would get a `Seq[Analysis]` for a classpath:

```
... (fullClasspath in Compile) map { (cp: Seq[Attributed[File]]) =>
   cp.map(entry => Defaults.extractAnalysis(entry)._2)
}
```

Note that the [implementation](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v0.12.3/main/Defaults.scala#L44) of `Defaults.extractAnalysis` gets an empty `Analysis` if there isn't one attached.

---

In 0.13, there is finally an API for doing this generally:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/snapshot/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks.html#multiple-scopes

In this case, it would look like:

```
someTask := {
   val allA: Seq[inc.Analysis] = compile.result.all(
      ScopeFilter( inAggregates(ThisProject), inConfigurations(Compile) )
   ).value
   ...
}
```

(The `result` part does the same as `mapR` in the direct syntax:
http://www.scala-sbt.org/snapshot/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks.html#result
)

Comment: This looks handy. Now if I really want to be annoying, my current solution using `AtomicInteger` is able to provide a running total to TeamCity by incrementing the counter with every subproject build. Is there some way to do that nicely, too?

Comment: I don't think so.  It would probably be in the form of https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/592 if it existed.