# Graphing sbt's incremental compilation logic

Tags: scala, sbt

sbt maintains dependencies between tasks, and the resulting graph can be reasoned about fairly easily. On the other hand, skimming the source code, it seems like the incremental compilation logic is a lot more opaque. I'd like to be able to do the following things:

- Say the equivalent of "if I modified this interface [in this way], what would get invalidated?"
- Build a graph of how modifying different class interfaces affects the rest of the build. Graphing scala import dependencies isn't a particularly good approximation of this, given how complicated implicit dependencies can get in Scala. It seems like sbt must maintain this information in some form or another to do incremental compilation, so I "just" need to figure out how to access it and hope that it's in a form suitable for my use case.

Are either of these feasible? I'm not opposed to writing sbt plugins, but would appreciate hints about how to proceed.

Edit: it looks like `Relation`'s `usesInternalSrc(dep: File): Set[File]` could be promising. Does that capture all of sbt's dependency knowledge?

Edit 2: even more promising, there's a `DotGraph` object inside the sbt source tree. It has no documentation and google doesn't have any human-readable text about it. If I can figure out how to use it I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample `console-project` session:

```
> val (s, a) = runTask(compile in Compile, currentState)
> DotGraph.sources(a.relations, file("source-graph"), Nil)
```

`source-graph` is a directory that will contain two dot files, one with source dependencies and one with binary.  You can alternatively directly interact with `a.relations` of type [Relations](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/api/#sbt.inc.Relations), as suggested in the question, and which does capture all of sbt's dependency knowledge.  In 0.13 there will also be information about which dependencies are due to inheriting from something in another source file.

In terms of how modifying a source file affects invalidation, it is very coarse grained.  Any change to any non-private signature marks a source as changed.  In 0.12 and earlier, this will at least invalidate direct dependencies and maybe more.  In 0.13, this will invalidate direct dependencies only, except for inherited dependencies, which are transitively invalidated.  There is currently no way to see what will be invalidated when a source file's non-private API is modified except by doing it.

Comment: DotGraph is internal and undocumented because it is raw and not really supported.  Really, I'd like to see attention on a proper inspect-compile command/task that is usable from the command line to debug these kinds of things.

Comment: Great, thank you! I managed to come up with something similar to that, but yours is simpler. Can you expand on how subprojects play into this? I tried looking for the `Analysis` of my aggregated superproject but it was empty (I guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092888/aggregating-analyses-over-sbt-subprojects is relevant). Do entire subprojects get invalidated or do the dependency graphs "reach in"?